# Geometry Nodes - Transfer tangent from curve to mesh (curve is a UV seam of mesh twig)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to **transfer tangent** from curve (which is basicly seam of twig)
but **transfer attribute** produce zeros for some reason

**The main problem is that Attribute transfer produces *zeros*, but Attrubute capture is working fine**

[Transfer Tangent.blend](https://pasteall.org/blend/3e40ab87c32d4f2a87e19a447db2eefa)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few reasons this isn't working..

- *Capture Attribute* captures a field of values on one state of the incoming  Geometry, and 'passes it on' down the green pipe: i.e. *down the same Geometry branch*. The output Geometry of your capture goes nowhere.. The attributes evaporate.
- The 'Target' ( personally, I wish it was called 'Source') of a *Transfer Attribute* node is the Geometry on which the attribute *resides*, ready to be transferred from one branch to another, in a manner similar to a *Data Transfer* modifier. Your 'Target' is the incoming mesh before a selection of it is  converted to a curve. It doesn't have the attributes you want to transfer.
- *Transfer Attribute* can't transfer from a curve (which is a formula for generating points).. only from a mesh or point-cloud, the locations of whose points are nailed down. A *Conversion to Mesh* will do, generating  points at which the curve is sampled. In this case, those are the original vertices, used to generate the curve in the first place.

[image]

Above, the Normal of the curve is sampled as well as the Tangent, in case you want a full orientation of the instances. If you want only the Tangent, the Normal is optional.

- An Euler 'Rotation' is a set of three angles. The Tangent and Normal are 3-vectors.. sets of three *lengths*. To use a vector as a guide to rotation, you can use the utility *Align Euler to Vector*.

Here, it's used twice. Once to align instance Y the Tangent, and then to spin around the (now set) Y, to align the instance Z to the curve's Normal.

[image]

I hope this is the sort of result you are looking for:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't look right.

Comment: @TheJeran remember..  the green arrows point down the tangent pf a poly-curve linearly interpolated,, as sampled a their bases? It looks OK to me .. maybe it would have been better to convert the curve to Bezier, and smooth it, before sampling? Also the sample is coming via 'Nearest', sometimes from the other side of the twig.

Comment: @TheJeran   Personally, I would want to _generate_  the twig from the curve  I sampled the direction from, rather than extract the direction-curve from an existing mesh? But this way is a nice idea,,